# Origin of particle "ли"

Tags: грамматика

Does anyone have a theory, or knowledge about the origin of the particle ли?

Why does it act as a question particle? Where did it come from, etc?

Comment: from `или`? then there's a second question: where does `или` come from? ))))

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Actually it's the other way round. `или` is `и`+`ли`.

Comment: It exists in many Slavic languages, so it comes from too dim and distant past. And theories... well, look into Vasmer dictionary: [ли](http://vasmer.info/%D0%BB%D0%BB/%D0%BB%D0%B8/).

Comment: curiously Vasmer says `укр. ли` while there's no such particle in the  Ukrainian, at least modern, just as there's no word `или`, it's even hard to compose a Ukrainian sentence with `ли`

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov, as Alex_ander says below `it adds the sense "или не/нет"` so `ли` could be a contraction of this long phrase, that is `или`

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка It could be if `ли` only ever occurred on its own or as part of `или`. Yet we have `али` and `либо`; the rest is Occam's razor.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov OK, makes sense

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov-- I don't understand your last statement) What do you mean?

Comment: `ли` occurs as part of several other compound conjunctions beside `или`, meaning that the proposition that `или` is another such compound requires less assumptions than the proposition that `ли` is a pared-down `или (нет)`.

Comment: Ukrainian has `чи` equivalent particle, however it is placed at the beginning of a clause rather than in the middle.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but there is also the Czech *-li* particle, which, as it seems to me, means 'if' or 'when': *Chceš-li mír, chystej se na válku* - 'If you want peace, prepare for war'; *Žiješ-li v Římě, žij po římsku* - 'Living in Rome, live the way Romans live'.

Comment: Sometimes it's quite hard to understand ли since the idea of "whether" has more or less gone from English in North America. Only "if" is used.

Comment: @VCH250 you must be talking about vernacular, because https://www.google.com/#q=%22whether%22+site:washingtonpost.com admittedly not millions of results, but not few either
and not once i've heard Americans say `whether you like it or not`

Comment: @  Баян Купи-ка I understand the word, but it really means the same as "if" for most people) —especially if one has to make a new sentence and not use a set phrase like "whether you like it or not"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(How it works in questions)

Whatever the origin of the particle is, it adds the sense "**или не/нет**" (whether or not). This could explain its function in *embedded questions*: it helps to simplify an expression by excluding the complete form of negated alternative.

> Он не знал, придёт **ли** [= **или не** придёт, придёт **или нет**]
>   сегодня его брат.

(He didn't know **if** his brother would come /or wouldn't come/ that night.)

In an *actual question* the sense "**или... не**" can be also (along with the mentioned simplification) used to express additional *doubt* about a judgment or about some its detail:

> А знает **ли** он об этом [**или** всё-таки **не** знает]?

(But does he *really* know about it?)

> А так **ли** это [**или** всё-таки **не** так]?

(Is it *really* so?)

Answer (score 6):

It is cognate of English *let*, comes from PIE root lee̯- meaning allow, idle, lazy, inactive. English words "left", "leave", Russian лень "lazyness" are of the same root.

Compare PIE forms ***lee̯nos*** "quiet", ***lee̯u̯os*** "left"